# Error al enviar email con django.core.mail

Tags: python, django, email

Nombre del error
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.core.mail.backends.smpt'` al enviar un mail con
 `send_mail('test email', 'hello world', 'lonzofrancisco@gmail.com', ['test@email.com'])` desde el shell

````
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'lonzofrancisco@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True   ```
````

he buscado informacion en la web de django pero no lo pude solucionar

[image: error completo que da]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hola por lo visto te falta la dependencia de la librería, debes instalarla con el siguiente comando:

```py
pip install django-smtp-ssl
```

Esto debe solucionar tu problema. Saludos!

Comment: Muchas gracias era eso!

Comment: Excelente @FranciscoLonzo No olvides marcarla como útil, así otros que tienen el mismo problema sabran que es la respuesta resuelve la problemática. Saludos!